# trying to avoid separated functions using settimeout

Tags: javascript, onclick, settimeout, onclicklistener

this script is doing a "roll over" on images 
on each mouse event e.g. mousover out and click

img src is changed, 
the problem is i was trying to delay 
the execution of the function 
executed by onClick event .

i tried to change function to settimeout but with no success

```
setTimeOut('functionName(param1, param2)', 5000);
```

nither calling a function that encapsulate the set time out

what am i doing wrong ?

```
       <a href="yourpage.htm">
    <img src="images/Button2_Normal.PNG" width="150" id="img2" 
onmouseover="mOver(this, image2)" onmouseout="mOut(this, image2)" onclick="mActive(this, image2)" />
                    </a> 

                    <a href="yourpage.htm">
          <img src="images/Button1_Normal.PNG"  width="150" id="img1" 
       onmouseover="mOver(this, image1)" onmouseout="mOut(this, image1)" onclick="mActive(this, image1)">
</a>
```

- javascript

  ```
  var image1 = new Array("images/Button1_Normal.PNG", "images/Button1_MouseClick.PNG", "images/Button1_MouseOver.PNG");
  var image2 = new Array("images/Button2_Normal.PNG", "images/Button2_MouseClick.PNG", "images/Button2_MouseOver.PNG");

  var preloadImages = new Array();  // preloads images
  function Loadimages(images) {

      for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
          preloadImages[i] = new Image()
          preloadImages[i].src = images[i]
      }
  }
  Loadimages(image1);


  lastN = ""

  function mOver(obj, images) {
      if (lastN != obj.id) {
          document.images[obj.id].src = (images.length == 3 ? images[2] : images[1])
      }
  }

  function mOut(obj, images) {
      if (lastN != obj.id) {
          document.images[obj.id].src = images[0]
      }
  }

  function mActive(obj, images) {
      var ts1 = document.getElementById('img1');
      if (typeof obj != "string") { obj = obj.id }

      document.images[obj].src = images[1]
      if (lastN != "" && lastN != obj) {
          document.images[lastN].src = images[0]
      }
      lastN = obj
  }
  function timeout_init(obj,images) {
      setTimeout('mActive(obj, images)', 5500);
  }
  ```

Comment: Never pass strings to `setTimeout`. Ever.

Comment: @jbabey ok that's a good one ... just so i know . and thanks for that as a starter to avoid thinking of current approach . dont have a clue as to solve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closure should work:

```
function timeout_init(obj,images) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    mActive(obj, images);
  }, 5500);
}
```

It's another reason to avoid `eval`-like functionality. With your current implementation JavaScript engine will take "`'mActive(obj, images)'`" string and try to `eval()`uate it in global context. By that time the original `obj` and `images` variables are long lost.

With closure your anonymous function will still have access to `timeout_init()` argument, despite that function finished. But variables survived as they were referenced by inner function.

Comment: thnks alot ! gonna give it a try

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters in `setTimeout` . which will be available as a arguments in  `mActive`.

```
   setTimeout(mActive, 5500, obj, images);
```

Comment: Just a reminder -- passing additional parameters in `setTimeout` does **not** work in our favorite browser (IE).

Comment: nice to knoow it's 'our' favorit i work in a company that use ie for the aplications

Comment: @LoneXcoder. Yes, Among all IE version till date only IE10 supports it(which is not released yet).